# Update 2 input file type fields with 1 browse action

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, filereader

How can I set the value of a file input field to be linked with the file chosen from another file input? So when user selects file in input1 then the input2 field is automatically populated with the file selected in the first. I was hoping to be able to do this with jQuery but I cant get it working:

Example:

```
<input type="file" name="input1" id="input1" onchange="previewImage1T1(this)" />
<input type="file" name="input2" id="input2">
```

Her is my attempt:

```
function previewImage1T1(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //the only jQuery line.  All else is the File API.
            $('#image1T1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#input2').val = input.files[0];
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help it would be greatly appreciated, I am sure its something really simple that I am overlooking

Comment: For security reasons I don't think you can change the value of a type file. Otherwise you could just select any file from the computer and upload it without the user knowing.

Comment: How about copying the value of the file within input1 and copying this to input2, is this possible?

Comment: that still counts as changing the value which is not allowed

Comment: Is there anyway of sending the file back to the main page without posting?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, as described in the MDN documentation: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#File_inputs)

As stated in the comments, this is because of security issues.